# HTML диалог открытия файла на андроиде

Tags: android, html

У меня имеется простая страница. На ней есть контрол для загрузки файлов на сервер. Я использую стандартный:

```
 <input type="file" />
```

На windows (в Хроме) все работает, а в андроиде после клика на кнопку "Выбрать файл" ничего не происходит. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я слышал, что загрузка файлов через веб-форму начала работать только с **Froyo**.
Разумного объяснения этому не наблюдается (по слухам, на айфоне как не работало, так и не работает до сих пор).

---

А вот и [тикет](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2519) нашёлся.